# Getting an ECONNRESET syscall read error inconsistently

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, request, pipe, cloudinary

I'm getting

```
{ [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
```

at seemingly random intervals. My code `GETS` a `jpg` from imgur and pipes it to cloudinary.

```coffeescript
requestOptions =
    method: 'GET'
    url: 'http://i.imgur.com/o5IQbOa.jpg'
    dataMode: 'raw'

stream = request requestOptions
cloudinaryStream = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream (result) ->
  console.log 'woohoo success'
, {public_id: data.cloudinaryId}
stream.pipe cloudinaryStream
stream.on 'error', (error) ->
  console.log error
```

It could work one time, then get that error 5 times in a row, then work 3 times then error out one time then go back to working. There isn't any pattern in the time between each success/failure. I delete the image off of cloudinary each time, though it doesn't matter and will succeed even if it's still there.

Any ideas as to what is causing this inconsistent behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary supports uploading automatically from remote URLs.
Can you try uploading directly from the URL and share whether it works better for you? 
e.g.,

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload('http://i.imgur.com/o5IQbOa.jpg', function(result) { console.log(result) }, {public_id: data.cloudinaryId});
```

Comment: No unfortunately, I can't. I'm getting the data back from an API call that isn't hosted anywhere and must pipe it directly. The imgur file was just an example.

Comment: What is the average file size of the uploaded images?

Comment: 6mb, they're PDFs. I'm limited to writing 500kb to disk if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: Sorry for my response delay. If it's still relevant, please share more information on this code. It looks like you're getting the error from the input stream. If you're running multiple concurrent uploads you may be running out of connections on your own server.

Answer (score -1):

This is error occur due to VPN connection, in My Project. When i upload userData to cloudinary

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).